# To print console.log message in active window console instead of background..

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I started building chrome extensions. Initially I started with a simple extension which prints the hello in background console. How can I print that in the active window console.

This is my manifest.json file

```
 {
     "manifest_version": 2,
     "name": "example",
     "version": "0.1",
     "description": "My Chrome Extension",
  "icons":  { 

    },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"] 
  },


  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "My test Environment"

    },

"permissions": [
    "background",
    "storage",
    "tabs", 
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
    ] 
  }
```

This is the content of my background.js file
a simple
               console.log("hello");

Comment: In general, if you're just starting, it's very important to read the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), you could use [`manifest.json` injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration) or [Programming injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) to ensure your code run in the context of current webpage.

- The former requires [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) or [Storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) to ensure communications between content script with background page;
- while as for the latter, Try the following code in `background.js`
  `chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: "console.log('hello');"});`